# scala worksheet: reverse typing

Tags: scala

May somebody explain me why when I am typing in a Scala Worksheet the letters are typed in reversed order?

`object exercise {
  )(pool fed //... 
} = tnI : )tnI :n(lairotcaf fed
}`

Comment: Maybe you have Left-To-Right direction defined (arabic, hebrew, etc)

Comment: I am using Eclipse L and the Scala version is functioning fine until I discovered that I am missing the worksheet part, so I installed it from here [link](http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-update-worksheet-scalaide40-211/site/). Now only in the worksheet the typing is reversed but not in a scala class (let say)

Answer (score 0):

Someone had that problem on the ML; it was temporary breakage:

[Here's the reply announcing a fix.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-ide-dev/cD1etknO0g0/ufzC_7urA5UJ)

Probably you must get the latest.

Comment: I have tried that "solution" before but it didn't function :(

Comment: Maybe you need to start `eclipse -clean`.